# forward declaration for thread function argument is not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, forward-declaration

i am trying to write a sample program for a class which will perform RAII and will call the thread with self this pointer. but data type for thread function argument is declared as forward declaration ahead.
Please have a look of the sample program -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class test; // **forward declaration**

void thfunc (test *p) {
    cout << p->value << endl;
    return;
}

class test {
    public:
        int value;
        thread t1;
        test () {
            value = 100;
            t1 = thread(thfunc, this);
        }
        ~test() {
            t1.join();
        }
};

int main () {
    test * p = new test;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

This is giving an compilation error -

```
fwd.cpp: In function 'void thfunc(test*)':
fwd.cpp:9:11: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class test'
fwd.cpp:6:7: error: forward declaration of 'class test'
```

To Fix this, i made the thread function as static member function of the class -

```
class test {
    public:
        int value;
        thread t1;
        test () {
            value = 100;
            t1 = thread(thfunc, this);
        }
        ~test() {
            t1.join();
            cout << "Dtor" << endl;
        }
        **static** void thfunc (test *p) {
            cout << p->value << endl;
            return;
        }

};
```

Is this a correct fix? I want to make thread functions as separate library, but now i have to make them as a part of class. Please suggest. Any kind of help/pointer/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what `p->value` is? It only had a chance to see `class test;`.

Comment: I fail to see the use case here. If you want to use the instance of the class in the thread function, you need to know what it looks like and as such the thread function in the other module would have to include the header describing the class. If you do not plan to use the instance, why pass it to the thread function in the first place? So I think the static member is making much more sense....

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Thanks. Idea was to create an object and pass it to multiple threads for processing. and when anyone deletes those object or they goes out of scope, threads should also shut down. hence i am trying to bound object to thread. But for the time being i will make them static

Comment: That would also work for static member thread functions. Multiple threads using the same static thread function.. and the join as shown in the answer below would do the trick as well. In order to prevent the thing from hanging in the destructor for arbitrary lengths of times, you might want to signal the threads that they are supposed to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `thfunc` a static member is correct in the sense it will work. If you wanted to keep them separate for a reason (and sometimes there are very good reasons), then you can still do that.

It's the function that can only declared before being passed as an argument to `std::thread`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void thfunc (class test *p);

class test {
    public:
        int value;
        thread t1;
        test () {
            value = 100;
            t1 = thread(thfunc, this);
        }
        ~test() {
            t1.join();
        }
};

void thfunc (test *p) {
    cout << p->value << endl;
    return;
}

int main () {
    test * p = new test;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats the exact trick i was looking for. you saved my day :)